# Logger.php deleting itself

Tags: php, logging

Whenever I launch a php site using Visual Studio code, my logger.php delets itself after a few seconds, making it impossible for to navigate further.
I had a first folder without any logger.php so I had to import a friend's folder with a working logger.php.

Comment: Hi. We aren't working on the exact same things as you are, so you'll want to clarify essentially everything above you said. "launch a site", "logger.php", "first folder" etc, we have no concept of what you have going on.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the lack of precision, I didn't know how to word my question as I felt desperate.
The site I'm talking about is a php file located on a folder in the wampserver installation folder.
Logger.php is a file that was required to access the site, located in .vscode (had to dig a bit to find the file).
The first folder I'm mentionning is the folder where the logger.php file should have been in the first place. But since there wasn"t one I just took the one of a friend, not knowing what the file did.
(Sorry for the first answer, I didn't know pressing enter would post.)

Comment: You either have code/scripts that remove the file, or it's infected with malware and your antivirus does. There's no builin feature called "Logger.php" you can just refer to by name and everybody knows, it's a custom development.